# Test if a redux connected component is rendered

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this presentational component that includes a `LoginForm` which uses redux connect... when i try to see if the component is there by using wrapper.debug(), instead of the component i see: `<Connect(Component) />`

What do i have to do in order to see the actual LoginForm and test its length?

This is my component:

```
const LoginSection = ({ intl }) => (
  <div className={styles.loginSection}>
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.form}>
        <p className={styles.title}>
          <FormattedMessage
            id="Dashboard.login.title"
            defaultMessage="Login to an account"
          />
        </p>
        <LoginForm />
        <p className={styles.createAccountWrapper}>
          <span className={styles.dontHaveAccount}>
            <FormattedMessage
              id="Dashboard.login.subline"
              defaultMessage="Dont have an account?"
            />
          </span>
          <a
            className={styles.createAccount}
            href={`${localeToDomainMap[intl.locale]}/register`}
          >
            <span className={styles.createOneHere}>
              <FormattedMessage
                id="Dashboard.login.createAccount"
                defaultMessage="Create one here."
              />
            </span>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

and this is my test:

```
const setup = (newProps) => {
  const props = {};

  const wrapper = shallow(<LoginSection {...props} />);

  return {
    wrapper,
    props,
  };
};

describe('LoginSection', () => {

  test('that it contains LoginForm', () => {
    const { wrapper } = setup();
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find('.loginFrom')).toEqual(1);
  });

});
```

and this is the result of `wrapper.debug()`:

```
  <div className="loginSection">
   ... other stuff here ...
        <Connect(Component) />
  ... other stuff here ...
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't worry about rendering and testing `LoginForm` in your unit tests for `LoginSection`.  You can render and test it in its own unit tests.

Comment: (but to answer your question, you would need to wrap the entire thing in a `Provider` component with a mock store and render it using `mount`...which is more of an integration test than a unit test)

Comment: but i'm already using shallow...  :/

Comment: ...and I agree that using `shallow` is the right way to test `LoginSection`.  I'm not recommending you use `mount`, I'm recommending that you render and test `LoginForm` in its own unit tests